# What does Class::* do?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've seen some examples for implementing `is_class` recently, and I'm wondering what the following syntax does:

```
Classname::*
```

For example:

```
template<typename T>
class is_class {
    typedef char yes[1];
    typedef char no [2];
    template<typename C> static yes& test(int C::*); // selected if C is a class type
    template<typename C> static no&  test(...);      // selected otherwise
  public:
    static bool const value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes);
}
```

What does the syntax `C::*` denote in this case? Does it just require C to have any members / be a namespace? I was unable to find any information about this.

Comment: It is the syntax for a [pointer to a data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer)

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks.  I wasn't 100% sure if I should use it or not.

Comment: What does it mean without a member name though?

Comment: @tobspr The same thing.  It is a function declaration parameter so it does not have to have a name.